# Dynamically generate client-side HTML form control using JavaScript and server-side Python code in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I have the following client-side front-end HTML using Jinja2 template engine:

```
{% for record in result %}
    <textarea name="remark">{{ record.remark }}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve" />
{% endfor %}
```

Thus the HTML may show more than 1 set of textarea and submit button.

The back-end Python code retrieves a variable number of records from a gql query using the model, and pass this to the Jinja2 template in result. When a submit button is clicked, it triggers the post method to update the record:

```
def post(self):
    if self.request.get('approve'):
        updated_remark = self.request.get('remark')
        record.remark = db.Text(updated_remark)
        record.put()
```

However, in some instances, the record updated is NOT the one that correspond to the submit button clicked (eg if a user clicks on record 1 submit, record 2 remark gets updated, but not record 1).

I gather that this is due to the duplicate attribute name remark. I can possibly use JavaScript/jQuery to generate different attribute names. The question is, how do I code the back-end Python to get the (variable number of) names generated by the JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited**

Inside the template **for** loop use [loop.index](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-control-structures): the current iteration of the loop.

Then:

```
{% for record in result %}
<textarea name="remark{{ loop.index }}">{{ record.remark }}</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="approve" value="{{ loop.index }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

return:

```
<textarea name="remark1">first record remark</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="approve" value="1" />
<textarea name="remark2">second record remark</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="approve" value="2" />
<textarea name="remark2">third record remark</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="approve" value="3" />
```

and in your backend code:

```
def post(self):
    if self.request.get('approve'):
        updated_remark = self.request.get('remark' + self.request.get('approve'))
        record.remark = db.Text(updated_remark)
        record.put()
```

I wrote this without testing it. Probably doesn't work, but could give you a hint.

---

**new [better] solution**

put each couple of textarea and input inside an form:

```
{% for record in result %}
    <form>
        <textarea name="remark">{{ record.remark }}</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve" />
   </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. The code looks good. However, the label of the submit buttons will now show 1, 2, 3 rather than Approve? If I change the HTML instead to name="approve{{ loop.index }}", is there an efficient way to change the back-end code correspondingly? Thanks.